# CMake non-configurable option

Tags: c++, cmake

In CMake, how can I define an option that is not configurable by the user, but automatically calculated?

I would like to do the following:

```
if (FOO AND NOT BAR)
    option(BOO "Foo and not bar" ON)
endif()
```

And then I can use `BOO` in different CMake files:

```
if (BOO)
    # do something
endif()
```

And also in sources:

```cpp
#ifdef BOO
// do something
#endif
```

So `BOO` behaves like a regular option, but is automatically calculated and not configurable by user running `cmake`.

**EDIT: I now realize that options are not implicitly available in sources, but need to be defined explicitly with `target_add_definitions` or other means. So now it becomes obvious that the solution is to define `BOO` as a CMake variable, rather than an option.**

Comment: `set(BOO ON)`? `if (BOO) target_add_definitions(${target} BOO) endif()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "non-user-configurable" option sounds like a variable, which you can create like:

```
if(FOO AND NOT BAR)
  set(BOO TRUE)
else()
  set(BOO FALSE)
endif()
```

To use this variable in C++ code, you need to tell CMake to create a C++ file which defines this information. Take a look at CMake's `configure_file` function. [Here's the official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html), and [here's part of the official CMake tutorial which walks through a simple usage of this function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20a%20Custom%20Command%20and%20Generated%20File.html). I would type out some example code, but it would be a lot of boilerplate, and the linked documents do the job and should be better at answering your questions.

There is an alternative to `configure_file`: using [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html). The tradeoff to make is between simplicity of implementation and build times. If the value of a compile definitions changes upon reconfiguration, then CMake has to assume that every source file of the target needs to be recompiled, since it has no information about how that definition is being used (ie. `target_compile_definitions` is easy to implement, but *can* lead to much slower build times in specific scenarios). When you use `configure_file`, only the files that include the file that defines those definitions need to be recompiled. There's also potentially an argumen to be made about "readability": if your target gets installed, it's easier for someone reading the installed headers to find the definition versus having to read generated CMake files to find it.

If for some reason you want this variable to be cached, you can make the cache variable hidden from regular view in [CMake's configruation GUI programs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/#interactive-dialogs) (`ccmake` and `cmake-gui`) by [marking the cache variable as being for advanced usage purposes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/mark_as_advanced.html).

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using a normal variable, but in some scenarios this information will not be available everywhere, e.g. if the subdirectory structure created by `add_subdirectory` does not ensure the information is required only in the `CMakeLists.txt` file where the info is introduced or in one of it's descendant directories.

In this case you should be using a cache variable with type internal `INTERNAL`. This has the added benefit of allowing you to persist the info for use during reconfiguration. You could also use `FORCE` to overwrite the value of any cache variable.

**Example**

```
if (... BOO not yet set properly ...)
    set(BOO_VALUE ...)
    set(BOO ${BOO_VALUE} CACHE INTERNAL "") # internal implies FORCE
endif()
```

Note that this won't make the preprocessor define available. You still need to use something like

```
target_compile_definitions(mytarget PRIVATE "BOO=${BOO}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use variable with `set(BOO <what you want>)`.

You can find the documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html

But there is no `option` that will restrict the value of your variable for an internal settings. Only you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `set()` does not evaluate condition expressions at least in any way that might be immediately imagined by your answer, which I find a little vague. This answer also doesn't show how to use the variable in a source file.

Comment: You're right `set` does not evaluate condition expression. For how you use a variable in CMake, I thought it was obvious since the person who ask the question knows how to use the `option`. Thank you for your comments, I will be more cautious when writing an answer :). Since your answer is what mine should have been, I will not edit my answer to avoid repeating what you said.